# how can i send the xml file to sever over https in ssis?

Tags: https, ssis

I would like to send and receive the xml files over https in SSIS. Please help me 
how can I send the xml file to sever over https in ssis without using any external third party tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script task.   The `WebClient` class will let you send a file over HTTPS with a POST operation.